# Stuck with canvas/JS animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm working on a game to play in canvas, and was wanting to add some ambiance to a background layer using javascript. To start, here is the code...

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var x = canvas.width/2;
  var y = canvas.height-150;
  var dx = Math.random() * (-5 * 5) + 15;
  var dy = -15;

  function drawDot() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.closePath();
  };

  function move() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawDot();
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
  };
setInterval(move, 50);
```

If you run that, you can see that what I have is a black ball that moves up and off the page inside a random conal space. What I need help with is figuring out the best way to:
 
A. Populate it with more balls (maybe like 2-3) that are on their own random trajectory, and
B. Make it so those 2-3 balls are constantly animating inside the random cone area off the page from the same starting area (kind of like a constant spurting fountain effect).

A problem I can already see is that by using the console log, the 1 working ball I have now just keeps going off into infinity outside the canvas, so when I try to add a new one it won't run the function.  I'm very new to javascript and especially canvas so apologies if this is obvious!
Thank you for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good tutorial by Seb Lee-Delisle on this exact problem here:

https://vimeo.com/36278748

Basically you have to encapsulate each `Dot` so it knows about its own position and acceleration.

**EDIT 1**

Here is an example using you own code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<canvas height="600" width="600" id="myCanvas"></canvas>';
clearInterval(interval);
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var dotArray = [];

function Dot() {
    var dot = {
        y : canvas.height / 2,
        x : canvas.width / 2,
        speedX : Math.random() * ( - 5 * 5) + 15,
        speedY : Math.random() * ( - 5 * 5) + 15,
        age : 0,
        draw : function () {

            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    };
    return dot;
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < dotArray.length; i++) {
        dotArray[i].draw();
        dotArray[i].age++;
        if (dotArray[i].age > 20) {
            dotArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    dotArray.push(new Dot());
}

draw();
var interval = setInterval(draw, 1000 / 60);
```